# How to hide properties and methods with an underscore in VSCode Intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I develop in Javascript with VSCode, and I don't want Intellisense to show class properties and methods which are private (i.e. with an underscore).

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: it is maybe because your method is private and therefore not accessible outside the scope of the class. Try changing it to public/export.

Comment: Update your question with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported by VSCode's built-in JavaScript language features.

For TypeScript code, you can use the `private` modifier, but for JavaScript, there is no story for marking a property as private. I've opened an issue against the TypeScript project to track observing the the `@private` jsdoc annotation as a starting point:  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14009

If you would like a more generic solution that marks all properties starting with `_` as private, please fill out a feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: Testing with the latest vscode and typescript does not appear to hide `@private` items from intellisense - anything marked `@private` is still visible. Is there a setting to tsconfig which needs to be enabled?

Comment: For me it does it without having anything set.  In what scope have you tested it?  If you are in the class scope for example having a private property then it is shown, outside not.  At least in my case.